# What does the parameter in the second lambda do?

Tags: lambda, scheme, sicp

This is from SICP Video Lectures, Lecture 2a around the 39:51 mark.

```
(DEFINE (SQRT X)
   (FIXED-POINT
      (AVERAGE-DAMP (LAMBDA Y (/ X Y)))
      1)) 

(DEFINE AVERAGE-DAMP
   (LAMBDA f
      (LAMBDA x (AVERAGE (f x) x))))
```

What does the `x` in the second lambda do in AVERAGE-DAMP and how is it being accessed? I don't understand what exactly is being passed to it.

Comment: I don't have the lectures at hand. Are you sure the lambda in the call to `AVERAGE-DAMP` is not `(LAMBDA Y (/ X Y))`?

Comment: @DiegoSevilla I've been eyeing that too.  It has to be `Y` for finding a fixed point and it being a square root to make sense (and syntactically unless Y is defined elsewhere).

Comment: Sorry, guys, you're right. I've corrected that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(DEFINE AVERAGE-DAMP
   (LAMBDA f
      (LAMBDA x (AVERAGE (f x) x))))
```

The tricky thing about this is that a function is being passed around here.

average-damp is a function of `f` that is defined as a function of `x` that is defined as the average of `f(x)` ("f of x") and `x`.

In other words, average-damp is a function that accepts another function, wraps a function around it, then returns this new function.

If you're familiar with JavaScript by any chance, this may help:

```
function average(a, b) {
    return (a + b)/2;
}

function averageDamp(f) {
    return function(x) {
        return average(f(x), x);
    }
}
```

So now think about, what is the following?

```
var something = averageDamp(function (c) { return c * 2 });
```

`something` is a function that takes one parameter, `x`, and returns the average of x * 2 and x.

In other words, it's like:

```
function (x) {
    return average(x * 2, x);
}
```

If you had:

```
var something = averageDamp(function (c) { return c * 2 });
something(5); //average(5*2, 5) = (10 + 5) / 2
```

This wrapping a function inside of a function is what is happening with your lisp snippet.

Edit: out of curiosity, I completely implemented a fixed-point sqrt approach in JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/tXDQL/.

Comment: @dotnetN00b Ah! Whoops.  It's 5*2.

Comment: @dotnetN00b That's because it doesn't output anything, but rather logs to the console.  Here's a version that writes to a div: http://jsfiddle.net/tXDQL/1/

Answer (score 1):

The value of `x` will be the argument that `fixed-point` passes to the function.

Now you didn't supply the definition of `fixed-point`, but from the name I would would imagine, it will first call the function with the argument `1` (because that's what was given as the second argument to `fixed-point`) and will then continue to call the function with its previous result as the argument until the result is the same as the previous result.

So on the first invocation `x` would be 1, on the second it would be `(average (f 1) 1)`, on the third it would be `(average (f (average (f 1) 1)) (average (f 1) 1))` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

`AVERAGE-DAMP` is just defined as a function (a lambda) that, when given a parameter `f`, returns another funciton (another lambda) that, when given a parameter `x` calculates the average of `x` and `f(x)`, where `f` is the previously received function.

Then, in `SQRT`, note how `AVERAGE-DAMP` is just called with *one* parameter (that happens to be a function, a lambda). This converts the call into another function (the second lamda in `AVERAGE-DAMP`), that, given a value, evaluates that given funciton `(LAMBDA Y (/ X Y))` to the given value. The `FIXED-POINT` function will take care of taking that function and evaluating the previous function for each the values it considers apropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
(DEFINE (SQRT X)
   (FIXED-POINT
      (AVERAGE-DAMP (LAMBDA Y (/ X Y)))
      1)) 

(DEFINE AVERAGE-DAMP
   (LAMBDA F
      (LAMBDA X (AVERAGE (F X) X))))
```

It might appear confusing at first, what I tried to help me clarify this when I was learning is to replace the "X" in the AVERAGE-DAMP with "Y". So that will help differentiate between the "X" as argument in SQRT.

```
(DEFINE (SQRT X)
   (FIXED-POINT
      (AVERAGE-DAMP (LAMBDA Y (/ X Y)))
      1)) 

(DEFINE AVERAGE-DAMP
   (LAMBDA F
      (LAMBDA Y (AVERAGE (F Y) Y))))
```

So what happens here is : 
F -> (LAMBDA Y (/ X Y)), 
then (F Y) -> (/ X Y), 
then (AVERAGE-DAMP (LAMBDA Y (/ X Y))) -> (LAMBDA Y (AVERAGE (/ X Y) Y))